# ProcessBuilder and the gobbler threads

Tags: java, processbuilder

When searching the web for tutorials how to run a sub process in Java and handle stdin, stdout and stderr I only find solutions with gobbler threads. Using gobbler threads means creating, scheduling and cleanup of 3 threads for every sub process call. If only a few processes are called this additional overhead doesn't matter, but if thousands of sub processes are called, e.g. compiling a lot of files, this overhead creates a measurable longer processing time. In addition using gobbler threads makes the implementation more complex.

So my question is why is it common to use a such inefficient and complex solution?

Below is a much simpler and more efficient solution:

```
private void runProcess() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  this.prc = new ProcessBuilder(this.commandLine.split(" ")).start();

  Iterator<String> it = this.getInputstreamList().iterator();
  StringBuilder stdOut = new StringBuilder();
  StringBuilder stdErr = new StringBuilder();

  try (BufferedWriter stdInBw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.prc.getOutputStream()), 65536)) {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      String line = it.next();
      stdInBw.write(line + "\n");
    }
    stdInBw.flush();
  }
  try (BufferedReader stdOutBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.prc.getInputStream()), 65536)) {
    try (BufferedReader stdErrBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.prc.getErrorStream()), 65536)) {
      while (true) {
        while (stdOutBr.ready()) {
          String line = stdOutBr.readLine();

          if (line == null) {
            break;
          }
          stdOut.append(line + "\n");
        }
        while (stdErrBr.ready()) {
          String line = stdErrBr.readLine();

          if (line == null) {
            break;
          }
          stdErr.append(line + "\n");
        }
        if (!this.prc.isAlive()) {
          break;
        }
        this.prc.waitFor(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      }
    }
  }
  this.retVal = prc.exitValue();
  this.stdOut = stdOut.toString();
  this.stdErr = stdErr.toString();
}
```

My tests have shown that the above solution works like a charm. But maybe I've missed something which makes the above solution unusable in special cases. Any hints or doubts?

Comment: *"So my question is why is it common to use a such inefficient and complex solution?"* Because 1) it is easy, 2) people are lazy, and 3) most applications *don't* launch enough external processes for this to be a significant issue.

Comment: Interesting question. I wish there were some expert responses. My uneducated concern would be if `waitFor(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` a) causes too many delays for processes that produce a lot of output and b) is enough to mitigate cpu overhead of the while loop for longer running processes that don't produce a lot of output